# How to turn off authoring information for a drupal page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is there a way to hide date and user info from a page post in drual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uncheck appropriate node type from Administer - Themes - Configure - right block: Display information on.

quick link: http://YOURSITE/admin/build/themes/settings

Recommend to use [theming nodes](http://drupal.org/theme-guide) - more powerful and flexible...

Comment: Anyone know where is this setting in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, check out the following.

Site Building > Themes > Global Settings

And uncheck the Content type under "Display post information on"

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck it from the Global theme config. Its the proper way to do it. Nodes like 'Page' you won't want submitted by on, but something like blog entry you would.

Answer (score -2):

You can remove it from the theme. Look for `$submitted` in your current theme and delete it.